# CPU throttling / parking under use

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage, intel-core-i7, cpu-throttling

Seemingly randomly, CPU cores 2-7 will park and cores 0-1 will throttle to an idle clock despite current heavy usage of a browser, video editor, VM, etc. What is running does not seem to affect the frequency or duration of the problem. This resolves only with patience, at any time between 30 seconds and 10 minutes after it starts.

I've checked for BIOS updates, etc. and all is up-to-date.

During:

[image]

Immediately after:

[image]

How can I diagnose this? I've not seen any consistent triggers.

Comment: use this tool to control the parking: https://bitsum.com/parkcontrol/

Comment: Nothing you have described so far indicates any sort of problem. What problem you are actually observing , what program your running, what things your doing at the time, are not described. There are even tasks that might seem difficult to accomplish that may not awaken all aspects of your cpu to do them, some that are adjustable but are not really problematic.

Comment: @Psycogeek I updated my question. The problem I am observing is that the processor will not clock above 0.75 on cores 0-1 despite heavy usage. All open programs become very slow, even the start menu is delayed (5-10 seconds) in opening.

Comment: in windows there is a setting (passive) in the advanced power properties "processor power management", "system cooling policy", that could possibly cause that, so it really would be a good idea to test a different bootup or os or test disk because the system can effect.  The thing I would want to do most here would be to see the temperatures, even in the bios/uefi. in windows the program OCCT might be useful in this case to both view temps (you can't be positive are reading right) voltages, and to torture the machine to observe what happens.

Comment: again, try the tool to control Parking and disable it if you don't care.

Comment: @Psycogeek I already confirmed that system cooling policy was set to active while plugged in. However, you reminded me to check HP CoolSense. The next time the issue appeared, disabling CoolSense fixed it immediately. I'll look into OCCT if the issue appears again, thank you!

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll try it if the issue reappears, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling HP CoolSense appeared to solve this issue. This is a localized answer to HP laptops, however.

Answer (score -2):

If it happens very frequently you could boot on a linux live USB, run it as normal, if does not happen then I would proceed to reinstalling windows.

Comment: I have already tried reinstalling Windows